# Do I need to be online to obtain Trophies on a PS4?

Tags: ps4

I just learned that unlike the PS3 or PS Vita, I can't view trophies offline on the PS4 (for the time being).  I am wondering, in order for me to setup/obtain trophies, do I need to be online or can I do this offline?

NOTE: By "setup trophies" I mean initially starting up the game, but not actually playing it. On the PS3 or Vita this would equate to starting up a game, but, then quitting out of it to view the trophies. (I do this as Disgaea 4 awards you a trophy for watching the intro. This way I don't earn any while I'm looking at the trophies.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trophies cannot be viewed offline with the PS4 like with the PS3 (you cannot toggle between online and offline), but you can still earn trophies by being offline. You will just need to connect online to sync them to your PSN account.

Comment: Do achievements get saved locally if you don’t even have a PSN account?

Comment: Yes, they are stored locally. If you later create a PSN account, these would be synced to your account.